# FTP sync over SSL/TLS started by command line

Tags: sync, ftp, ssl, tls

I have webspace and develop locally. When I have finished my local changes, I want to synchronize using FTP with SSL/TLS (I do not mean openssh's sftp/scp) with my webhoster (with no ssh access so also no rsync or similar) using a simple command; that is to say it should only upload/delete the changes.
I do not want to open a FTP client with or without a GUI and manually upload and delete files on the remote site.

I know that sitecopy does it but not over SSL for FTP (it does SSL over Webdav).

Do you have a hint for this (special?) usecase since I have not found any tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[weex](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=weex&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) can be used for that purpose. I could not find it using search engines but via https://packages.debian.org/sid/web/sitecopy and the "similar packages" section on the right. It is interesting that https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/sitecopy does not mention weex!